# How does one make a HashMap from two ArrayLists?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have two ArrayLists:

```
ArrayList<Integer> keySet = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

and

```
ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
```

How would I create a HashMap using the keySet ArrayList as the keyset in the hashmap and the values ArrayList as the values in the HashMap?

Comment: Be careful, the question smells a little bit of misunderstanding `HashMap`. A key is always associated with the value you give it. The answer below will associate them by their index order, but any modifications after that and the two collections will diverge. `HashMap` alone also does not preserve order, your keys won't necessarily print in the same order you put them in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the length is the same:

```
HashMap<Integer, String> a = new HashMap<>();
for(int i = 0; i < keySet.size(); i++) {
    a.put(keySet.get(i), values.get(i));
}
```